# Nested for loop using Python

Tags: python, pandas

the goal is to replicate df9 from df0 with nested for loop

here is df9 (intended outcome)

```
df9 = pd.DataFrame({'outer':[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3],'inner':[1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3]})
```

here is the attempted replicate from df0

```
df0 = pd.DataFrame({'outer':[1,2,3]})
for i in df0['outer']:
 for j in range(3):
    df0['inner']=j
```

here is the actual outcome (wrong)

```
df_wrong = pd.DataFrame({'outer':[1,2,3],'inner':[2,2,2]})
```

Can someone help me understand what's the issue in my code?
Thanks

Comment: You didn't share what the actual outcome is versus your intended outcome

Comment: Please read [ask]. ["Can someone help me?" is not a valid question here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/4518341), so please ask a specific question, although your code has multiple issues (wrong range, not adding new rows, assigning a scalar to a column), so you'll want to identify them first. To start, you could try printing `df0` on every loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**

Append rows to a dataframe is pain, prefer build a list with your nested loop and create the dataframe from it:

```
data = []
for i in df0['outer']:
    for j in df0['outer']:
        data.append((i, j))

df9 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['outer', 'inner'])
print(df9)

# Output
   outer  inner
0      1      1
1      1      2
2      1      3
3      2      1
4      2      2
5      2      3
6      3      1
7      3      2
8      3      3
```

But a vectorized way is to use `np.tile` and `np.repeat`

```
import numpy as np

df9 = pd.DataFrame({'outer': np.tile(df0['outer'].to_numpy(), df0.shape[0]),
                    'inner': np.repeat(df0['outer'].to_numpy(), df0.shape[0])})
print(df9)

# Output
   outer  inner
0      1      1
1      2      1
2      3      1
3      1      2
4      2      2
5      3      2
6      1      3
7      2      3
8      3      3
```

Comment: Doesn't look like nested `for` loops to me.  Doesn't explain the OP's issue, which is what the question asked.

Comment: It's not possible to use nested loops without use `append` on a DataFrame which is deprecated. Feel free to propose an alternative rather than DV.